# Ionic ngx-translate store translation for offline access when translations are loading from server

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I am creating ionic4 multi-language application.
All the translation files are coming from the server.

When translations are loaded from the server, I want them to store, so that it can be accessed when the device is offline.
If there is not internet on the first start, it should load English from assets folder but prefix in translation loader is URL of the server like below,

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, shared: SharedService) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'SERVER_URL', '.json');
}
```

So how to add prefix based on condition?
And store translation for offline usage as well?
I tried to search on many forums but didn't find any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

we can use missingTranslationHandler when it fail to get translation files from the server , the second part is to cash the translation files in the localstorage

**cash the language files in localstorage**

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor( translationService: TranslateService) {

    ['en','tr','de'].forEach(lang => {
      translationService.getTranslation(lang).subscribe(res => {
        localStorage.setItem(lang,JSON.stringify(res))
      })

    })
  }
}
```

**missingTranslationHandler implementation**

```
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    const currentLang =  params.translateService.currentLang;
    const langFile  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(currentLang)) || {};
    return langFile[params.key];
  }
}
```

**set missingTranslationHandler provider**

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  missingTranslationHandler: {
           provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler
  },
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
})
```

Comment: But then what about the translations that I have to get from the server?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya I find missingTranslationHandler is the only way to handle this

Comment: But I need to have two options to load the language.
If there is no language cached in storage, and the internet is not available, get translation from /assets/i18n, if the internet is available, then get it from the server.

Comment: why the app start a request will be made to get the translation file after that the translation file will store in memory this how ngx-translation work so even if the internet is gone the translation will still work

Comment: But that is for the current session. what is app closed and open next time in offline?
It should show the last translation loaded from the server.

Comment: yes the data will be load from localstorage what the problem in that case ? but the main problem is when you open the app first time as offline

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer is meant to cash the request translation file but we don't use the local in any case ,in here we will load the language translation file as static json like this

```
import en from "src/assets/i18n/en.json";
import tr from "src/assets/i18n/tr.json";
```

**missingTranslationHandler implementation**

```
export class MyMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
    const currentLang =  params.translateService.currentLang;
    switch (currentLang){
    case 'en': return en[params.key];
    case 'tr': return tr[params.key];      
    default  : return en[params.key];
  }
}
```

**set missingTranslationHandler provider**

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  missingTranslationHandler: {
           provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: MyMissingTranslationHandler
  },
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
})
```

for the loader it's the same you don't need to change any thing

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, shared: SharedService) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'SERVER_URL', '.json');
}
```

you will got an error related to resolveJsonModule not enabled

```
Cannot find module 'src/assets/i18n/en.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension
```

another error related has no default export like this

```
TS1192: Module '"D:/lab/src/assets/i18n/en"' has no default export.
```

just enabled these options in tsconfig.json

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true

  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Everything was done properly. But still, the text is not appearing on offline mode.
What to do now?